# How can I enable my app to access a specific partition directory for reading and writing without showing popup to user?

Tags: android, permissions, operating-system

I am currently developing an app for the Android Automotive OS, named com.oem.myapp, which is designed to store data in a specific partition (/data/vendor/LargeData). The app is targeted at Android API version 33. I have encountered a couple of issues:

1. MyApp is unable to access files in the /data/vendor/LargeData partition despite their presence, which appears to be a permission issue. Do the read/write_external_storage permissions cover this directory as well as all other directories?
2. To secure the necessary permissions in advance, What code should I modify in Android? I aim for MyApp to obtain these permissions automatically, without displaying a permission request popup to users.

I heard topic about "scoped storage" or "App-specific storage", can not find information for that.

Any advice on these matters would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Only if your device was rooted your app would have access to that location. And then without any permission i think. Who placed those files there? A normal path would be /data/data/<package> or /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm aware that the paths you mentioned are the standard ones. However, my intention is to use an external path through a mounted directory. The files in this path are either written during the Android build process or uploaded via adb push. It's possible to modify the Android build code to apply this. Additionally, I'm looking into granting permission rights at the build time. If there are any relevant settings, I would like to assign some sort of permission for this purpose.